# Scaffold MySQL table with composite primary key in Grails

Tags: mysql, grails, scaffolding, composite-primary-key

```
package website

class Translations {

    String content;

    /* Primary key consists of language_id and text_id */

    static constraints = {
        content();
    }

}
```

Everything is clear for tables with single primary keys.

But I wonder how to handle with composite keys.

Is it possible to scaffold those tables, using Grails 2.1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's directly supported, though there are some additional requirements for your domain class. See 
the GORM documentation at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#compositePrimaryKeys

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I still haven't solved my issue, but at least now I know where to dig.

Comment: Just to clarify: composite keys are supported in GORM, but not in the scaffolding. You have to manually change the views and controllers to handle composite keys.